# Hadoop streaming sort error

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I am trying to sort a file using hadoop streaming.

The file format is as follows

```
<ID> <TextID> <Offset> <Text> - where ID is alpha numeric, TextID is alpha numeric and Offset is numeric
```

I want to do something like ORDER BY ID, TextID, Offset ASC

I am using the following hadoop streaming command:

```
 hadoop jar /apollo/env/SEOHadoopClient/lib/hadoop-streaming-0.20.205.0.jar \                           
-D mapred.output.key.comparator.class=org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.KeyFieldBasedComparator \
-D stream.num.map.output.key.fields=3 \
-D mapred.text.key.comparator.options="-k1 -k2 -k3n" \
-D mapred.text.key.partitioner.options=-k1,1 \
-input /user/sakul/hadoop-streaming-sort/output \
-output /user/sakul/hadoop-streaming-sort/sort-output \
-mapper org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityMapper \
-reducer org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityReducer \
-partitioner org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.KeyFieldBasedPartitioner
```

But I get the following exception in the mappers:

```
   java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, recieved org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1014)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$OldOutputCollector.collect(MapTask.java:592)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityMapper.map(IdentityMapper.java:38)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:436)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:372)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1059)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

I'm putting this here in the hope that it helps you, even after so long, but also because I have forgotten the solution to this issue several times already.

As you may have gathered from the Exception, IdentityMapper expects `<K,V>` in `Text,Text>` format.  The default input format (org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat) provides `<LongWriteable, Text>`, so it must be changed using the -inputformat parameter:

```
hadoop jar /apollo/env/SEOHadoopClient/lib/hadoop-streaming-0.20.205.0.jar \                           
-D mapred.output.key.comparator.class=org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.KeyFieldBasedComparator \
-D stream.num.map.output.key.fields=3 \
-D mapred.text.key.comparator.options="-k1 -k2 -k3n" \
-D mapred.text.key.partitioner.options=-k1,1 \
-input /user/sakul/hadoop-streaming-sort/output \
-output /user/sakul/hadoop-streaming-sort/sort-output \
-mapper org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityMapper \
-reducer org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityReducer \
-partitioner org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.KeyFieldBasedPartitioner \
-inputformat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.KeyValueTextInputFormat
```

I use org.apache.hadoop.mapred.KeyValueTextInputFormat, which splits info at the first tab or, "If no such a byte exists, the key will be the entire line and value will be empty." Since this is a sort, that sounds like the behavior you want, though I may have misunderstood you.

Comment: Thanks. I worked around by using -mapper="cat" -reducer="sort -k1" etc.